# How to fetch the data from database using spring boot without mapping

Tags: spring

I have a database and in that database there are many tables of data. I want to fetch the data from any one of those tables by entering a query from the front-end application. I'm not doing any manipulation to the data, doing just retrieving the data from database.

Also, mapping the data requires writing so many entity or POJO classes, so I don't want to map the data to any object. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Take the query as String from the request then directly execute that with JDBC template or as native query and then return the retrieved resultset the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, assuming the mapping of tables if not relevant, you don't need to use JPA/Hibernate at all.

You can use an old, battle tested [jdbc template](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate) that can execute a query of your choice (that you'll pass from client), will serialize the response to `JSONObject` and return it as a response in your controller.

The client side will be responsible to rendering the result.

You might also query the database metadata to obtain the information about column names, types, etc. so that the client side will also get this information and will be able to show the results in a more convenient / "advanced" way.

Beware of security implications, though. Basically it means that the client will be able to delete all the records from the database by a simple query and you won't be able to avoid it :)